# Label sequences by group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID_1' : ['i1','i1','i1','i1','i1','i1','i1','i1'],
             'ID_2' : ['a1','a1','a1','a1','a2','a2','a2','a2'],
             'label':['a','b','b','a','a','a','a','b']})
```

I would like to get an id for the sequences of `'label'` for each group `('ID_1' , 'ID_2')`, so that the output would be :

```
ID_1    ID_2    label   seq_id
i1      a1      a       1
i1      a1      b       2
i1      a1      b       2
i1      a1      a       3
i1      a2      a       1
i1      a2      a       1
i1      a2      a       1
i1      a2      b       2
```

If the group was not a concern, this would have worked :

```py
df['id_seq'] = df['label'].shift(1) != df['label']).cumsum()
```

So I tried to adapt it with the following :

```py
df['shifted_label'] = df.groupby(['ID_1','ID_2']).label.shift(1)
def get_sequence_group(grouped) :
    return (grouped['shifted_label'] != grouped['label']).cumsum()
df.groupby(['ID_1','ID_2']).apply(get_sequence_group)
```

But it's not working at all. Would like to understand why and how to proceed. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it completely vectorized, we can groupby on the diff with `shift`. This way we avoid using `apply`

```
diff = df['label'].ne(df['label'].shift())
df['seq_id'] = diff.groupby([df['ID_1'], df['ID_2']]).cumsum()
```

```
  ID_1 ID_2 label  seq_id
0   i1   a1     a       1
1   i1   a1     b       2
2   i1   a1     b       2
3   i1   a1     a       3
4   i1   a2     a       0
5   i1   a2     a       0
6   i1   a2     a       0
7   i1   a2     b       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  I think you were close; use `groupby` and `transform` with your logic:

```
df['seq_id'] = df.groupby(['ID_1', 'ID_2'])['label']\
                 .transform(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).cumsum())
```

Output:

```
  ID_1 ID_2 label  seq_id
0   i1   a1     a       1
1   i1   a1     b       2
2   i1   a1     b       2
3   i1   a1     a       3
4   i1   a2     a       1
5   i1   a2     a       1
6   i1   a2     a       1
7   i1   a2     b       2
```